# java networking slow on windows machine

Tags: java, sockets, networking, communication

I written some simple client server application - the server accept connection, the client send 100m data and then the connection closed.

i have a dual boot machine, when the application running on linux it performed 10 times faster then on windows (tried 7 and xp)

Why is that?

BTW 
an equivalent code written with perl runs the same on both the OS's (6 times slower then java on linux but much faster then java on windows)

**Edit**
Here is a small code example

```
private static void runServer() throws Exception {
    try(ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT); Socket s = ss.accept()){
        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BYTES; i += in.read(chunk)) {
            continue; //empty for!
        }
        System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }
}

private static void runClient() throws Exception {
    byte[] chunk = createJunk(CHUNK_SIZE);
    try (Socket sock = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)) {
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        for( long toSend = CHUNK_SIZE, sent = 0;
             sent < NUM_BYTES;
             sent += toSend, toSend = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, NUM_BYTES - sent))
        {
            out.write(chunk, 0, (int) toSend);
        }
        out.flush();
    }
    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```

The client is always run from a windows machine that is different from the server machine but in the local network.

Comment: could you give us some more information (server info, some source code, any loops that you may have, etc)

Comment: If you run both server and client on the same machine you are effectively measuring how fast the OS is passing the data from one process to another. An "equivalent" code in another language is not *equivalent* in terms of runtime behavior - I wouldn't take this as indicator for anything.

Comment: what if you wrap your input and output streams in BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream?

Comment: also, how do you create junk data? have you tried measuring its performance on different platforms?

Comment: The Client creates a junk array of CHUNK_SIZE size, and then sends it all in one write, doesn't it?. I mean if you remove the for the code will run exactly the same? I'm asking to check if I understood the code correctly.

Comment: @Denis Tulskiy
the junk array is a simple 1024 bytes array with '1' on each array cell (a very simple for) - as the client itself is not "changing" (i not testing its performance but the server performance) i not sure it is important,

Comment: @pmoleri no - the client send NUM_BYTES bytes in chunks, if i will remove the for it will only send CHUNK_SIZE bytes.

Comment: @bennyl now I see, you keep sending the same junk once and again. Wild guess, try `sock.shutdownOutput()` instead of flush in the client. Perhaps the Client has a delay sending the tcp termination sequence and the server keeps waiting for more data until a timeout is reached.

Comment: @pmoleri thanks, i will try when i will be back at home.. i will post here the result. (in the mid while - please post your comment as an answer so that i will be able to accept it if it solve the issue)

Comment: @pmoleri the runtime was definitely improved by adding this line, still there are differences between the OS's, but linux is only 3 times faster now..